# Error occurring while downloading data and graph to excel in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have added data and graph to an excel sheet.Now while i try to download these,fist time am getting it correct and the next time onward it starts to show some error.And also i have given a path to save the file.How can i make that to download to the browser.Please help me in this as i am new in this. Am using MVC.

controller.cs

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;


    //using System.Windows.Forms;

    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



    namespace ExcelDownload
    {

        public class HomeController : Controller
        {

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }


            public void download(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {




                Excel.Application xlApp;

                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;



                xlApp = new Excel.Application();

                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);



                //add data 

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Student";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "English";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Maths";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Physis";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Chemistry";



                xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Term1";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "80";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "65";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "45";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "45";



                xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Term2";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "78";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "72";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "60";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "45";



                xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Term3";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 2] = "82";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 3] = "80";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = "65";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5] = "45";



                xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1] = "Term4";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 2] = "75";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 3] = "82";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 4] = "68";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "45";


                xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 1] = "Term5";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 2] = "75";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 3] = "82";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 4] = "68";

                xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 5] = "45";

                Excel.Range chartRange;



                Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);

                Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(500, 80, 300, 250);

                Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;



                chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "E6");

                chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);

                chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;



               // xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\Student.xls", //Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, //Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, //misValue);
string filePath = string.Empty;
filePath = Server.MapPath("~/excelfiles/" + fileName);
FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(file);
                    xlWorkBook.Dispose();

                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

                xlApp.Quit();



                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);

                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);

                releaseObject(xlApp);



                //MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");

            }



            private void releaseObject(object obj)
            {

                try
                {

                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);

                    obj = null;

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    obj = null;

                    //MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());

                }

                finally
                {

                    GC.Collect();

                }

            }



        }

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
         @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    @{using (Html.BeginForm("download","home"))
    {
         <div>
            <button>Download</button>
        </div>
    }}



    </body>
    </html>
```

The error what it shows after the first download is "Cannot access the student.xls"

Comment: U need to give excel sheet a new name every time you save it.
Your SaveAs method must be throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue comes when using the same file name for Excel each time.
Either you delete the Existing file by checking

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
```

and then Saving using

```
            Request.Files["exampleInputFile1"].SaveAs(filePath);
```

or Generate random number for you excel file like

```
  var now = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  string my3DigitRandomNumber = now.Substring(now.Length - 7, 3);
  fileName = (file.FileName.Replace(extension, "")) + (my3DigitRandomNumber + extension);
  filePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/excelfiles"), fileName);
  file.SaveAs(filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.but how can i save the file with out specifying the any path. Any way for that by considering my code. This is where i save the.So by avoiding this path specification...?   ' xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\Student.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
'

Comment: U didn't get me
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\Student.xls",      Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
Give random excel file name here or delete the existing one before saving

Comment: I understood that but what i meant is that in normal case when we download some file from net, it automatically downloads to the download folder.Same way, can i do that by considering my code. Because may the path what i have added won't be there in someone else system if they rub this code.So please help how to do it..

Comment: Add this in your controller
     using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        string filePath = string.Empty;
                        filePath = Server.MapPath("~/excelfiles/" + fileName);
                        FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        wb.SaveAs(file);
                        wb.Dispose();
                    }

Comment: Can you please modify my code according to that because when i tried with it, its not working.please help because i am just a starter in this field.

Comment: Check Now and do add a folder with the name excelfiles in your solution

Comment: After reviewing only it wil be visible to you.Comment
    // xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\Student.xls", //Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, //misValue, //Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, //misValue, misValue, misValue, //misValue);
And Add these
    
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    filePath = Server.MapPath("~/excelfiles/" + fileName);
    FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create,     FileAccess.Write);
                    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(file);
                    xlWorkBook.Dispose();

Comment: Made the changes what you told,but the downloaded file is empty and also the dispose is not working so i have to comment that also.If you have time please run my code, and see whats wrong in it.

Comment: I use ClosedXML for Excel Creation. I dont know what is need to be referenced for Excel

Comment: Check the excefiles folder whether the folder contains data on not

Comment: Yes the folder contains the file but when that excel is opened no data is available. I don't understand whats the ClosedXML ..?

Comment: ClosedXML is a plugin To make WorkSheet(excel workbook) in C#

Comment: Actually am writing the data and graph to the excel. So can i get it worked with this ClosedXML plugin.Because the graph which is shown is based on the data in the excel

Comment: No error, but the data is added through this line  xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\Student.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
       before i guess

Comment: You can do that 
See this link
    http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dd27d4/import-data-to-excel-insert-a-chart-and-convert-excel-to-pd/

Comment: I have gone through that site and find it useful.Thanks for it.But one doubt, if i make any changes to the data in the excel will that be resembled in to the graph also.Because that was my requirement.

Comment: After your excel is fully complete, graph will be same if the value is changed by the user in the excel

Comment: i tried with the code shown in that site,but while using the ClosedXml am getting error even after adding the dll reference

Comment: it has a dependency `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`. make sure you install both